# Some apps not opening on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, application

I've some apps on CentOS 7.5 with GNOME that won't open when clicked.
The **Weather** app for example, when clicked, it seems to load, but does nothing.. it doesn't open.

I found a similar issue here, saying the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js` should be changed on line 77 with value `this._app.open_new_window(-1);`, but i found it's already changed.

It has already open on the beginning of installation but for some unknown reason it's not opening anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There's likely another process that's running that's blocking it or there's a file that's blocking it, such as a lock file.

In a terminal you can try launching it manually to see what's up.

```
$ gnome-weather
```

If you don't see anything specific using that method, then you need to start tracing it. I typically do it like this:

```
$ strace -s 2000 gnome-weather
```

Debugging with `strace` can be a little daunting, so start by looking at your `/home` directory to see if there's a file that's blocking it.

```
$ strace -s 2000 gnome-weather  |& grep -E open | grep -i /home
```

Then look at `/etc` & other directories to see if it's hanging on any particular file access (read/write).

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Executing `gnome-weather` does nothing, and `strace -s 2000 gnome-weather` renders information I can't understand, as you have said it's daunting.
Thank you anyway. I'll keep trying and see what happens.

Comment: Take the output from `strace` cmd and post it on https://pastebin.com/ so I can see it.